# Let $X$ and $Y$ are copies of $S^2$ taking points $x_1,x_2 \in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ then $\pi_1(X \bigsqcup Y/x_1\sim y_1,y_2\sim x_2 )?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Recently I have been reading Hatcher's algebraic topology book; in chapter zero, there is a problem that if take the sphere of dimension $2$ (symbolically $S^2$)and identify two points on $S^2$ then it is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$. Now I have a question here if we take two identical copies of $S^2$, call it $X$ and $Y$; I am taking two different points from $X$, say $x_1~and ~x_2 \in X$ and, taking two points from $Y$ say $y_1~ and ~y_2 \in Y$.
Let $Z$ be the quotient space defined by identifying the points $x_i$ with $y_i$ for $i=1,2$
i.e
$Z=X \bigsqcup Y/x_1\sim y_1,y_2\sim x_2 $, is $Z$ homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$?
Actually, I want to find the first fundamental group of $Z$.

Comment: Yes. The first identification of $x_1,y_1$ creates $X\vee Y$. Now the space is connected, so identifying any pair of points in it is adding one $S^1$ summand. (Subject to usual nice basepoints, no crazy topology etc. disclamers which are satisfied in your case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $Z\space{\sim}{\space}S^2\space\vee{\space}S^1{\space}{\vee}{\space}S^2$ by homotopy equivalence. You can think of the equivalence working like this picture, where the two spheres are retracting along sides of the circle.

[image: Homotopy equivalence of two spheres joined in two points]

Since the homotopy equivalence of spaces yields an isomorphisms between fundamental groups, you have $\pi_1(Z)\cong\pi_1(S^2\space\vee{S^1}\space\vee{S^2})\cong\pi_1(S^2)\ast\pi_1(S^1)\ast\pi_1(S^2)\cong\pi_1(S^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, since fundamental group of $S^2$ is trivial, and fundamental group of a wedge sum of space is isomorphic to free products of fundamental groups.